# Advertising integer on python callback

Tags: python, ros

I'm writing a plugin in python-based ROS, so when I run the package and press a button in my GUI, it will advertise an integer value of 1 on the get_queue callback, signaling true. I define the callback as:

> def getqueue_cb(self):
>
> self.get_queue_pub.publish(1)

and above in the code I have:

> self.get_queue_pub = rospy.Publisher('get_queue', int(1), queue_size=10)

When I run the package in ROS, it glitches. When I comment out the second part of the code I have written here, the rest of the GUI pops up and runs fine. I feel like my problem is with the syntax for integers. Let me know what I'm doing wrong if you can.

Comment: Hi, I wonder, if my my answer solved your problem. If yes, please accept the answer (see also [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work); if not, it would be nice to leave some comment, that it did not work. This helps us to organize this site, as I and other users can see, if the problem is resolved or if there is still need for help. (and last but not least, it gives me some feedback if my answer was correct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly publish integers, but you have to use one of the "integer messages" defined in `std_msgs`.  Try the following:

```
from std_msgs.msg import Int32
self.get_queue_pub = rospy.Publisher('get_queue', Int32, queue_size=10)
```

(The second argument of `Publisher` expects the message type, not an actual value.)